# How to list missing dependencies of Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project with 100's of dependencies. Some of these dependencies are not available.

When I run `mvn install` against the parent pom file (this parent pom references the other projects) then I receive errors that some Maven dependencies cannot be found. But I have to add those dependencies before I can discover what other dependencies may be missing.

Is there a Maven command which will list of the missing dependencies for a project ?

Update : 
Another options is to clear out repository folder and attempt to rebuild with Eclipse/Maven plugin - missing dependencies for all projects appear to be listed in problems tab

Comment: yeah this is annoying when you need to send messages to colleagues with repo modification privileges. I've spent the whole afternoon doing this and am irritating him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven shows you all dependencies that are missing in the first tier. It's impossible to show also traversing dependencies because without poms included in those dependencies, Maven has no information about further dependencies. So only solution in that situation is to add all missing dependencies (absolutely with pom files) and then re-run maven (`install` or just `mvn dependency:resolve`)